# Can a site hosted with Squarespace be configured to work with IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, squarespace

There is no info on squarespace.com regarding IPv6 support and even squarespace.com does not have any AAAA records present. This leads to the question:

Can my website hosted on Squarespace be reached via IPv6? If so, where should the DNS records point to in order to reach my website?

Comment: Your website can only be reached on IPv6 if it has IPv6 address, that is a `AAAA` record in the DNS **and** your webserver is configured to listen on that IP address and has virtualhosts attached to it. You seem to reply yourself in fact because you know to check for `AAAA` for your provider, so you need to do the same for your own website name.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I was asking about Squarespace and not about how IPv6, DNS and Webservers work together.

Comment: " If so, what DNS records need to be there to reach my website?" the reply to this is the same for any webhosting company, there is nothing specific to Squarespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is best practice to have an ipv6 address](https://serverfault.com/questions/935550/should-my-website-have-an-ipv6-address), yet [Squarespace does not have an ipv6 address](https://twitter.com/squarespacehelp/status/203204918042050561?lang=en).

Yes, Squarespace does not follow best practice, and no, there is no way to fix it besides to wait for them to update their systems.

It should only affect a very, very small amount of your users who are both (1) on ipv6-native networks and (2) with a malfunctioning NAT.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Yes it probably only affects a tiny amount of users. But it is disappointing that a provider in the size of Squarespace is not capable of implementing IPv6 in the year 2019.

Comment: @rimshot It's not just disappointing, but deeply concerning. These days, if a web hosting business isn't offering IPv6 it calls into question whether they will actually be in business long term.

Comment: @rimshot FWIW neither does `wordpress.com`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a AAAA record present it is most likely automatically generating a record to the IPv4 server.

Either that or it forces the IPv4 connection on the device attempting the IPv6 connection.

I have only ever experienced issues with having the correct server value set for the IPv4 record and (accidentally) had the IPv6 point to the old server I was using, causing a whole host of issues on certain devices. But, I just deleted the IPv6 record and 24 hours later the change had propagated and it was resolved (I now don't have an IPv6 record declared - but it works swimmingly).

This is what I have experienced with other host sites (not squarespace).